# Core Dump with trying to take command line arguments. (C++)

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I have been experimenting with C++ command line arguments and have run into a few problems. Originally I was trying to compare "argv" with a string using the "==" operator. I quickly learned that that compares the pointers not the values. I fixed that error but now i am getting this one at run time.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The program compiles fine, and I'm not getting warnings from the compiler either. Here is my source code so that you can help me find the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Deal with arguments and send them to the correct functions
    if (argc >= 2){

        string op = argv[2];
        if (op == "-a" || op == "--automatic"){
            cout << "Test";
        }

        return 0;
    }
    //Or, just write help and info
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "bwc v0.0.1U-(Unstable)\n\n";
    cout << "Usage: bwc <operation> [...]\n";
    cout << "Operations:\n";
    cout << "   bwc {-a --automatic} <file(s)>\n";
    cout << "   bwc {-i --interactive}\n";
    cout << "   bwc {-c --error-codes}\n";
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you call your program? I guess you should use `argv[1]`, not `argv[2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexing of `argv[]` is off by one. Change:

```
string op = argv[2];
```

to:

```
string op = argv[1];
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the simple answer, I'll be more careful next time.